# Not able to see icons on my desktop

Tags: 11.10, unity, icons

I am not able to see icons on my desktop even when I have minimized all my windows. Also I am unable to right-click on my desktop. I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Vaio Laptop. I am using Unity 3D.

Comment: While you may have some success (using CCSM, etc.), by design Unity wants you to use the launcher (button bar, left side of screen) instead for all icons and starting applications.  You may need to look at loading Gnome Desktop .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to adjust the setting without having to install gnome-tweak-tool & gnome-shell, ect. then in a terminal

```
gsettings set  org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

Or in dconf-editor (requires installing dconf-tools) just follow above path - org > gnome > desktop > background, enable "show-desktop-icons"

Answer (score 5):

First, install `gnome-tweak-tool` if it's not already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Start it with Unity-Dash search "Advanced Settings" or type in command line:

```
gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then check the settings shown below:

[image: Gnome Tweak Tool]